# MediaElement.js: How to show time in format 00:00|00:00

Tags: mediaelement.js

I've discovered in code options timeAndDurationSeparator, but without success. How to use it? 
Exists way how to show time in format "00:00 | 00:00" (current time + separator + duration)?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it through options "features". I didn't knew that is possible change order of features. I'm surprised that so important information isn't described on web site. When you change order of features through options ie. instead of "features: 'playpause', 'current', 'progress', 'duration', 'tracks', 'volume', 'fullscreen']" you set "features: 'playpause', 'progress', 'current', 'duration', 'tracks', 'volume', 'fullscreen']", your player is rendered with "Current time" close to "duration". After that you can add border in styles for current span and it's solved.